# How to define compile-time (static) constant inside a C++ class?

Tags: c++, class, constants, class-variables

I have some constants that only need to be used at compile-time to simplify code, so I don't need the actual variables available at runtime.

Traditionally the way this was done was with `#define NAME 123` but I would like a type-safe alternative.

Outside of classes you can `const int name = 123;` which works fine, but it doesn't seem possible to put this inside a class.  For example this:

```
class Example {
    public:
        const double usPerSec = 1000000.0;
};
double usOneMinute = 60 * Tempo::usPerSec;
```

Works with Visual C++, but doesn't work with GCC:

```
error: non-static const member ‘const double Example::usPerSec’,
  can’t use default assignment operator
```

You can fix it by making it static, but then Visual C++ complains:

```
error C2864: 'Example::usPerSec' : a static data member with an in-class
  initializer must have non-volatile const integral type
    type is 'const double'
```

I'm guessing this means VC++ will only accept `static const int`.

I want to avoid setting the value in the constructor because then I need an instance of the class at runtime in order to access the value, whereas really I want it all handled at compile time like it is with `#define`.

So how can I define a constant as a `double` inside a class, without resorting to making it global or using `#define`, that will work without having an instance of the class, and that will function with major C++03 compilers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a difference here between integral and other types. For integral types you can always define them as `const static` members as in

```
struct Example
{
    const static int name = 123;  // added 'static' to code in text of question
    const static unsigned usPerSec = 1000000;
};
```

For non-integral types, such as `double` in your example, the situation is more complicated. Since 2011 (using compiler option `std=c++11` with most compilers), you can simply do this:

```
struct Example
{
    constexpr static double usPerSec = 1000000.0;
};
```

But with gcc, this

```
struct Example
{
    const static double usPerSec = 1000000.0;
};
```

should work also in C++03 (it's a GNU extension).

However, the standard approach in C++03, which is also used by the standard library itself (for example in `std::numeric_limits<>`), is a `static` member function

```
struct Example
{
    static double usPerSec() { return 1000000.0; }
};
```

Comment: `+1` for mentioning `std::numeric_limits<>`, I feel that's a useful point.

Answer (score 4):

I see two possible approaches with C++03:

1. Use a static member function and rely on inlining:

   ```
   class Example {
       public:
           static double usPerSec() { return 1000000.0; }
   };
   double usOneMinute = 60 * Example::usPerSec();
   ```
2. Use a static data member and resign on constant folding (the value using the constant will be computed at runtime):

   ```
   class Example {
       public:
           static const double usPerSec;
   };
   double usOneMinute = 60 * Example::usPerSec;

   // Somewhere in one .cpp
   const double Example::usPerSec = 1000000.0;
   ```

Comment: The second option gives unresolved externals if you use it in a library and compile with MSVC++.  Having to export the symbol in a DLL is definitely overkill for a supposed compile-time constant that wouldn't normally be visible outside the library!

Answer (score 2):

If I were you I would put it in a namespace:

```
namespace MyExampleNamespace {
    const double usPerSec = 1000000.0;
}
double usOneMinute = 60 * MyExampleNamespace::usPerSec;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code works on both vc++ and gcc :

```
class Example {
public:
    static const double usPerSec ;
};
const double Example::usPerSec=10000.0;
double usOneMinute = 60 * Example::usPerSec;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it static const and then give it value outside class. Don't do it inside constructor. You don't have to make make instance

```
class Example {
public:
    static const double usPerSec;
```

};

```
double Example::usPerSec = 1000000.0;
```

Now you can use it anywhere without making any instance of class

```
double someVar = Example::usPerSec;
```